# Rsyncmirror failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com Connection timed out

Tags: repository, rsync, timeout, localrepository

Noob to Ubuntu-22.04.2
I am trying to setup a local repository by downlaoading the jammy packages from the archive.ubuntu.com by using the Rsyncmirror. this is the issue am running into.
link to setup Rsyncmirror:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror

Issues that I am getting:

```
root@ubnserver01:/opt# /repo/UbuntuMirror/mirrorbuild.sh
Mirroring to /repo/UbuntuMirror/ubuntu-mirror from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Arches: amd64
Dists: focal,focal-security,focal-updates
Sections: main,restricted,universe,multiverse
Pdiff mode: use
Will clean up after mirroring.
Attempting to get lock ...
Updating remote trace files (using rsync) ...
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (185.125.190.39): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (185.125.190.36): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.38): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.39): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): Network is unreachable (101)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (2620:2d:4000:1::19): Network is unreachable (101)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15): Network is unreachable (101)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::18): Network is unreachable (101)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(139) [Receiver=3.2.7]
Warning: failed to use rsync to download extra files.
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/focal/Release...   #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/Release ==> 403 Forbidden
Download of dists/focal/Release failed: 403 Forbidden
[  0%] Getting: dists/focal-security/Release...          #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/Release ==> 403 Forbidden
Download of dists/focal-security/Release failed: 403 Forbidden
[  0%] Getting: dists/focal-updates/Release...   #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/Release ==> 403 Forbidden
Download of dists/focal-updates/Release failed: 403 Forbidden
Errors:
 Download of dists/focal/Release failed: 403 Forbidden
 Download of dists/focal-security/Release failed: 403 Forbidden
 Download of dists/focal-updates/Release failed: 403 Forbidden
Failed to download some Release, Release.gpg or InRelease files!
WARNING: releasing 1 pending lock...
```

Any Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A lot of repeated references and also reference to 20.04 focal. Are you trying to do 20.04 or 22.04?

Comment: This is regarding to version 22.04, Are there solutions to these repeated references?

Comment: Then way are you trying to access focal stuff?

Comment: I am not familiar how ubuntu repository is structured, This is learning curve. I am not familiar with focal,focal-security,focal-updates and if it is related to 22.04. Should i remove the focal* ?

Comment: My goal is to have a local repository that i can control when syncing with the Ubuntu repo site and only upload 22.04 packages for security updates along with any other packages that is compatible with 22.04. All of my client server with 22.04 will report to local repository server for updates/patches.

Comment: There might be a ratelimit if you're pulling too quickly.  How frequently are you trying to clone / rsync data down?

Comment: Update: I just noticed that i am pointing to the wrong distro of focal* and pointing to jammy* for 22.04.

Comment: @ThomasWard,  I don't believe i have set a ratelimit on the rsync. I am currently trying to get the local repo connection working.

Comment: I didn't say *you* had a ratelimit, I'm saying the remote might.  I see timeouts in your environment though, it sounds like you might be blocked by a firewall rule, etc. in your environment

Comment: I am currently asking the firewall team to check the port 873/tcp rsync and have them open the port. Hopefully this will fix timeout issue.

Comment: Yes I was telling you that you were trying to use 20.04 not 22.04

Comment: @David, yes i did not realized that focal was the name for 20.04. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ok issue have been resolved. I had to get the firewall and the proxy configured to open for port 873. Thanks again for your assistance.